# GCP Cloud Function Cold Start Error with Retry

Tags: google-cloud-functions

In the last couple of weeks there we have been observing an increase in errors during a function cold start.

When we call a correctly deployed GCP function (Node10 runtime, europe-west3) which is publicly available (allUsers granted Invoke Cloud Function permission).

The request returns the following:

```
https://project-id.cloudfunctions.net/http-triggered-functions  500     
      <html><head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
      <title>500 Server Error</title>
      </head>
      <body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
      <h1>Error: Server Error</h1>
      <h2>The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.<p>Please try again in 30 seconds.</h2>
      <h2></h2>
      </body></html>
```

It seems like this issue has a smaller probability in the evenings (region: europe-west3). 
It also seems that this issue has a bigger probability on projects with small amount of function calls.

This behaviour is not covered by documentation.

The GCP logging does not show any line related to that incident.

Comment: What (if anything) is being logged in Cloud Logging logs?  I think you are showing what is returned to the caller of the function but not what is being recorded by the internals that has encountered the error.

Comment: Is something getting logged? could you please include the logs, and be more specific on the issue as stated in [How to ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: No, there is nothing logged .

Comment: @JoséSoní I've added some information.

Comment: could you share the code that is getting this behavior?

Comment: @JoséSoní The problem is that invocation of a "cold" function does not succeed. IMHO the spinup of the function container does not succeed and the corresponding code never starts to run. Also note that there is no log statement at all. We've deployed about 100 different functions and that problem occurs randomly over those functions. Mostly in dev stages with sparse traffic.
This is a quality of service issue and not a implementation problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Investigating more with the information you shared I got that actually this is a Known issue with Cloud Functions with NodeJS.

In [Long cold start times in Node.js applications](https://issuetracker.google.com/158014637) you can follow up the updates the google team will be posting.

They also mention that it is not depending on the actual code deployed and there are no known work araounds there

In the[Github Issue](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-node/issues/2942) there is mentioned this [partial workaround](https://github.com/samcorcos/firestore-rest)however it only addresses the delay caused by the startup of communication objects with firestore.

The other mentioned workaround is to move the code to [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/quickstart) as it supports warmup calls and there is more control on developer's side.